# qemu newbie: vm startup stopped at 'booting from hard disk'

Tags: qemu

I have successfully started an Arch install but now want to import a previous VirtualBox VM into kvm through qemu.

The ported system is vdi->qcow2 for the boot disk. I can mount the qcow2 to another qemu system running the arch installer, and have verified the systemd-boot entries for that disk.

But when I try to start the new system using the qcow2 disk as the only disk on the system the console comes up with  'Booting from hard disk' and stops there for at least half an hour now.

Comment: I think I saw something like this recently. Is it a uefi image? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671966/booting-from-real-uefi-disk-image-on-qemu

Comment: @eftshift0 Ah yes. That'll be it. I'll run it in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Booting from real (UEFI) disk image on QEMU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671966/booting-from-real-uefi-disk-image-on-qemu)

Comment: @eftshift0 Yup. I had to install edk2-ovmf and then in the manager GUI set the firmware option.  But now I have another problem for another question. Thanks.